# manifest.plist file is displaying only as text

Tags: ios, plist, manifest, ipa

I uploaded a plist file but when I go to that link to get the ipa, the plist file is only displaying the text, and not doing anything else. Something is going wrong here and I don't understand what.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://rentaid.info/clarktest/Clarktest2.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.rentaid.testapp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Clarktest2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: how is the URL to the .plist formatted? Did you include `itms-services://`?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot just open the *manifest* file via standard HTTP scheme becasue nothing useful will happpen. you need to create a link to your *manifest* file with a special scheme, and that link can work on the device only.

the link with the custom sceme should look like this:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://rentaid.info/clarktest/manifest.plist
```

*IMPORTANT: make sure your server **has** proper SSL certificate, because on iOS7 or above the device won't download the IPA file, if the hosting server has no SLL certificate.*

Answer (score 0):

Just uploading the plist file and try to open up willn't help you to get the app. you should hyperlink like this

```
   <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/Application.plist">
    Install This App
  </a>
```

[Check this out tutorial 1](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/)

[Check this out tutorial 2](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air)